# Custom TableView - Data gets cleared during reload

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

i have did one sample project using Custom `tableView`. In this custom `TableView,` in each cell i have two `textFields` and two `buttons.` my issue is, when i add or delete a cell(row) to the `tableView,` the data in the previous cell(in the `textFields`) gets cleared. That is, when the `tableView` gets reloaded, the data in the `textFields`(inside the row) gets cleared.

You can directly download the [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lowbgnqzk05ej8d/Alert.zip)

Comment: what have you done by now , please post your code

Comment: Are using binding or doing programmatically??

Comment: It won't save your data unless you manually stored them into core data or sql or any other way.. Then, how could you expect that it should stored there? Its not possible with your code..

Comment: i don need it to store the data.. i jus want the tableView to retain the data of the first cell when the other cell is deleted.

Comment: did you understand? @Praveen

Comment: Yes i understood.. And, i'm trying in some ways

Comment: No... still not achieved it.@Praveen

Comment: @Praveen https://www.dropbox.com/s/lowbgnqzk05ej8d/Alert.zip

Comment: i have faced same issue in my code...